# Profiling .NET Web App with No Code

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, performance, load

I have a .NET web application running on a server that is suffering and eventually failing under load. Is there any kind of profiler I can run without having access to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use profilers like [Ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/) or [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), or even the built in profiler in Visual Studio premium.

Both Ants and dotTrace have time limited evaluation versions so you can easily try them out for a while.

The profiler can run without source code or debug symbols, but without at least debug symbols (*.pdb) you might have a hard time to interpret the result.

You will also have a hard to fix any problems if you don't have any source code. You could in theory disassemble the code with [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx), fix the bug and then reassemble the code with [ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx), but that is not as easy as fix it in the code.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Ants will fit the job nicely and is just what I'm after.

Answer (score -1):

If there's a database involved, that's usually your best chance for improvements.  This is especially true if you don't have any code - you can tweak database indexes and sometimes get huge gains without ever seeing the code.

Comment: Not really what I was asking. Can you have another go or remove your answer?

Comment: I can't help you find a profiler. But I won't remove the answer, and here's why.  You have a problem - you have a slow application.  Asking for a profiler narrows your options.  Even if you're investigating the database separately or have the option eliminated for other reasons, this answer has value - value for others with a similar problem, and value for you as bait for others who are just thinking about solving the real problem.

Comment: But you missed the point of the question, and in fact the while question. "Is there any kind of profiler I can run without having access to the code?" You have been marked down accordingly. Happy to change it when you have something to offer.

Comment: No, I didn't miss it.  I just don't have a ready answer for that part of the larger problem.  Since you don't address this obvious best solution to the problem in your question, it's worth posting the suggestion as answer, if nothing else for the reason stated above.  I'm also a little concerned that you won't at least consider or respond to the suggestion, as this really is your likely best route.

Comment: If you don't have the answer, ready or otherwise, either research it and find out, or just observe what others do.

Comment: I have an answer to your problem -- and a good one at that.  One that's very likely more worth your time than the one you asked for.

Comment: But I'm after a best solution for a profiler with no code. Databases have nothing to do with the problem posed. The problem is not having direct access to the code. So you DO NOT have an answer to this specific question so you have no answer with any value in this instance.

Comment: My position is that you still fail to see your real problem.  Your problem is **not** that you can't find a profiler.  That's the question you posed, but it's only one aspect of the full problem. _The actual **problem** is that you have a slow web app_, and that's a larger issue than just looking for a profiler.  Limiting yourself to looking for a code profiler hurts your ability to solve the real underlying problem, especially because of code profile won't be able to look into any database issues, which almost always have more impact.

Comment: You have completely missed the point and are wrong on two counts. Firstly, I don't have a slow app, I have an app that fails under load (read the question not what you think I am asking). Secondly, I am after a way of profiling assemblies on a web server when I do not have the code. Your focus immediately went to databases, but for all you know, I have no database in my solution. There are heaps of generic performance questions on SO and this is not one of them. What's your problem? Realise your failing on this occasion and learn from it; answer what is being asked not what you want to answer.